# Can I generate an image from jqplot's jqplotToImageStr({}) function in IE 8 and previous?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, jqplot

I rely on jqplot's jqplotToImageStr({}) function to generate a png as base64 string from my chart. Then I'm sending the base64 representation to the server to do my job. The problem is that jqplotToImageStr({}) returns null when the browser (<= IE 8) does not support canvas. Is there a way I can successfully use jqplotToImageStr({}) even in browsers unaware of canvas?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is not possible. We check string input at server side and return a message to user if the input is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try the javascript below (copied from jqplot sample). Append it to the end of the page.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){if(!$.jqplot._noCodeBlock){$("script.code").each(function(c){if($("pre.code").eq(c).length){$("pre.code").eq(c).text($(this).html())}else{var d=$('<pre class="code prettyprint brush: js"></pre>');$("div.jqplot-target").eq(c).after(d);d.text($(this).html());d=null}});$("script.common").each(function(c){$("pre.common").eq(c).text($(this).html())});var b="";if($("script.include, link.include").length>0){if($("pre.include").length==0){var a=['<div class="code prettyprint include">','<p class="text">The charts on this page depend on the following files:</p>','<pre class="include prettyprint brush: html gutter: false"></pre>',"</div>"];a=$(a.join("\n"));$("div.example-content").append(a);a=null}$("script.include").each(function(c){if(b!==""){b+="\n"}b+='<script type="text/javascript" src="'+$(this).attr("src")+'"><\/script>'});$("link.include").each(function(c){if(b!==""){b+="\n"}b+='<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" hrf="'+$(this).attr("href")+'" />'});$("pre.include").text(b)}else{$("pre.include").remove();$("div.include").remove()}}if(!$.jqplot.use_excanvas){$("div.jqplot-target").each(function(){var d=$(document.createElement("div"));var g=$(document.createElement("div"));var f=$(document.createElement("div"));d.append(g);d.append(f);d.addClass("jqplot-image-container");g.addClass("jqplot-image-container-header");f.addClass("jqplot-image-container-content");g.html("Right Click to Save Image As...");var e=$(document.createElement("a"));e.addClass("jqplot-image-container-close");e.html("Close");e.attr("href","#");e.click(function(){$(this).parents("div.jqplot-image-container").hide(500)});g.append(e);$(this).after(d);d.hide();d=g=f=e=null;if(!$.jqplot._noToImageButton){var c=$(document.createElement("button"));c.text("View Plot Image");c.addClass("jqplot-image-button");c.bind("click",{chart:$(this)},function(h){var j=h.data.chart.jqplotToImageElem();var i=$(this).nextAll("div.jqplot-image-container").first();i.children("div.jqplot-image-container-content").empty();i.children("div.jqplot-image-container-content").append(j);i.show(500);i=null});$(this).after(c);c.after("<br />");c=null}})}$(document).unload(function(){$("*").unbind()})});
</script>
```